# Retain object without using a property

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, retaincount, ivar

I have a control that works like this:

```
MyCustomControl *control = [[MyCustomControl alloc] initWithNavigationController:self.navigationController];

control.completion = ^{
    [self controlCompletedAction];
};

[control showFromView:self.view];
```

However, since it's not retained by anything, the control gets bad access when trying to call some methods.

Retaining the control in a property of the calling class works fine, for example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MyCustomControl *control;
```

or

```
@interface MyViewController {
    MyCustomControl *control;
}
```

both work fine.

However I'd rather not add properties for each different control I am making.
The purpose of the control is to separate functionality in order to avoid massive view controllers. The property is not responsible for anything else in the view controller, so there is no reason to keep it around.

So, is there a way to retain the control ***not*** using a property/ivar or resorting to the objc runtime?

Comment: What methods are getting the bad access? Can you post the code where it crashes?

Comment: By the way, retain should be replaced with strong (retain is pre-ARC)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instance variable (essentially a global variable) instead of a property if you wanted to. It would look something like this:

```
@interface YourClass {
    MyCustomControl *control;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *should* use a property, because properties communicate the notion of *ownership*, which makes your code easier to understand and maintain.

Perhaps you are reluctant to make the control a property of the view controller that is instantiating it because it does not **belong** to that view controller.  The question then becomes, to what does the control belong?  If it belongs to the Navigation Controller, consider subclassing the Navigation Controller and adding your control as a Navigation Controller property.

If the control is a subclass of UIView and will be added to the view hierarchy, it does not need to be retained as a property because it will be retained by its superview and released when it is no longer in the view hierarchy.

If my suggestions don't make sense to you, can you provide more information about the control itself?

Comment: The control is not necessarily added to the calling view hierarchy. The purpose of the control is to separate functionality in order to avoid massive view controllers. The property is not responsible for anything else in the view controller, so there is no reason to keep it around.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `static` variable inside your custom control class, but only if there is only one instance of `MyCustomControl` at the same time (like popover, but even it requires strong variable).
code example:

```
// MyCustomControl.m

static MyCustomControl * _currentInstance = nil;

-(void)showFromView:(UIView *)fromView

{ [_currentInstance dismiss];

// show code here ...

_currentInstance = self;

}

- (void)dismiss

{ // remove your control

_currentInstance = nil;

}
```